# Why does javascript change the data type on Array.push?

Tags: javascript

I was working on a small javascript coding challenge that was simple enough, but ran into a odd bit of strange behavior that I couldn't find documented anywhere. Maybe someone could point me to where it states that this is expected behavior?

```
myIntegerArray = [1,2,3,4];
b = new Array();

for(var v in a)
{
    b.push(v);
}
console.log(b); // returns ["1","2","3","4"]. Note String result
```

If I were to use the `forEach()` however I get an array of Numbers back:

```
a.forEach(function(element,index,ay)
    {
        b.push(element)
    });
//a console.log(b) will return [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Your code won't produce that output. The array would be zero-indexed, not one-indexed.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I looked at my result again and so it is. Should have clued me in, but I was so distracted by the apparent type change that I missed it altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pushing the key name, not the value. You need to to do this:

```
b.push(a[v]);
```

This might help you understand:

```
for (var key in obj) {
  var value = obj[key];
  arr.push(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var v in a)
```

In JavaScript, Arrays are just like Objects. `for..in` loop will get the keys of the Array objects, which are the actual array indices. As we know that, JavaScript Object keys can  only be Strings. So, what you are actually getting is, the Array indices in String format.

And another reason why `for..in` should not be used, is in MDN docs. Quoting from [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

> for..in should not be used to iterate over an Array where index order
>   is important. Array indexes are just enumerable properties with
>   integer names and are otherwise identical to general Object
>   properties. There is no guarantee that for...in will return the
>   indexes in any particular order and it will return all enumerable
>   properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are
>   inherited.
>
> Because the order of iteration is implementation dependent, iterating
>   over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order. Therefore
>   it is better to use a for loop with a numeric index (or Array.forEach
>   or the non-standard for...of loop) when iterating over arrays where
>   the order of access is important.

So, you either use

```
for(var index = 0; index < array.length; index += 1) {
    array[index];
}
```

Or the `forEach` which you have shown in the question itself.